# In Magento 2 How can I display ui_component base grid column based on if else condition

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I want to display certain column of grid based on condition,I need hint/suggestion.I used this tutorial for creating a grid in magneto2
https://ranasohel.me/2014/04/20/creating-magento2-adminhtml-grid/.
I used ui_component for creating a grid.Because in magento 2 ui_component use xml to display grid.How can I add if else condition in magento 2 ui_compoenent grid.

for example like magento 1.x grid column

```
if($condition == true){
$this->addColumn('price', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Price'),
            'index' => 'refund_amount',
            'width' => '80px',
            'column_css_class' => 'a-center',

        ));  
 }
```

**app/code/Test/Testimonial/view/adminhtml/ui_component/testimonial_blog_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New testimonial</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="testimonial_blog_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PostGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="disable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massDisable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="enable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massEnable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="testimonial_blog_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="SR\testimonial\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">testimonial/blog/edit</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: What kind of conditions ? Based on a configuration field ?

Comment: I want to if..else{} condition on ui_component based grid certain or column where I can hide column base on if else

Comment: I still don't understand the type of condition. Is that based on the value of a field ?

Comment: not value of field but if my condition true so it should display perticular column else not display that column.check my edited question

Comment: I added magento 1.x grid column example .I want like that in ui_component base grid in magneto 2

Comment: Yeah I understand that but depending on what kind of condition it will not be the same answer please post the exact condition

Comment: I want to hide column based on role wise.if admin logged in in admin role so admin will see all columns and other role('managers,sales') not display all columns.do you get it ?

Comment: Ok that makes sense I'll check it out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your app/code/Test/Testimonial/view/adminhtml/ui_component/testimonial_blog_listing.xml

add in the column tag the class attribute:

```
 <column name="nameofyourcolumn" class="YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MyColumn">
```

MyColumn class is:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;

class MyColumn extends Column{

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        if(!in_array(1,$authSession->getUser()->getRoles())){
            $data = [];
        }
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory,$components, $data);
    }

}
```

in your case YourVendor/YourModule is equal to Test/Testimonial

in the $authSession variable you have all information about the authenticated user.
In the if which you can read above, I want that if the authenticated user is not an administrator (1 is the ID of the administrators group for me) don't show the column. To achieve this I put an empty array in $data variable, which contains all data printed in the column, as result I don't see anymore the column.

Comment: Ok wait I am checking

Comment: Yes it is working thank you very much.You can award from this my question.plz help me in this url http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117980/magento-2-0-2-to-magento-2-0-7-upgrade-fail-during-readiness-check . I am in trouble in this question.I tried but not solved and not magento 2 upgrade.plz check